# Symfony/ Twig: Filter-filter a collection

Tags: symfony, filter, twig

Newbie here. Using Symfony 3.4.

I have a Collection of EntityType formtypes I created with the form builder. I'm trying to deposit them on the page *selectively*. I'd like to loop through them all several times on my template, spitting some of them out according to specific criteria (for instance, the value of a "HiddenType" subtype).

For instance, let's say I had a collection of Movies, some of which have a "Rating" HiddenType. My task is to spit them out selectively in several separate "Rating" sections (i.e. all the R-Rated movies in a single section).

Edit: But! Ratings are user-imputed; dynamically-generated elsewhere. So I can't just make a finite amount of "sections" ahead of time.

My first thought was

```
{% for rating in ratings %}
   <h1>{{rating}}-Rated Movies</h1>
   {% for movie in form.movies %}
       {% if movie.rating = "R" %}
           {{movie}} // put movie formtype/ collection member here somehow...?
       {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

But I also read that twig has a "filter" filter:

```
{% for rating in ratings %}
   <h1>{{rating}}-Rated Movies</h1>
    {% for movie in movies|filter(m=> m.rating == rating) -%}
        {{ m }} //put movie formtype/ collection member here somehow...?
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Either way, though, I can't really reconcile the functions I'm familiar with for converting forms to actual html (e.g. `form_row()` ) with the either of these methods.

Any ideas?

Comment: What you are trying to do is unclear. Are you trying to populate a select box with movie titles that are rated R? This would be done in the form class, not in the template. You would use an EntityType and use a custom query to limit the results to just the rating you want. https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities

Comment: @craigh That totally makes sense in the "movie" example I wrote. I perhaps oversimplified my example. In the actual case, I won't know ahead of time what the possible "Ratings" are. In my actual use-case, I need to go through a list of dynamically-populated "ratings" atop each section.

Comment: You could fetch the list of possible ratings beforehand in your controller if that helps to create the needed `form_rows`

Answer (score 1):

You need to order the movies in your Form by rating. Then in your template do something like this:

```
{% set rating = null %}

{% for movieForm in form.movies %}
    {% set movie = movieForm.vars.value %} <= check if this is the movie entity by dumping it
    {% if movie.rating != rating %}
        <h1>{{ movie.rating }}</strong>
        {% set rating = movie.rating %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ form_row(movieForm) }}
{% endfor %}
```